# Android - play different sound on ever second click

Tags: java, android, button, audio

If I want to play a sound when a user clicks a button it is:

```
Button one = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);     

one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 
    public void onClick(View v){ 
    mp.start(); }
    });
```

But what do I do when I have 2 sounds and I want to play a diffrent sound on every second click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int iClicked = 0;
public void onClick(View v) 
{ 
    iClicked++;
    if(iClicked % 2==0){
       // Do sth, e.g. play sound I
    }
    else { // Do sth else, e.g. play sound II
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    private int rId=0;//class member
    //onclick
    final int [] music={R.raw.soho,R.raw.other};
    int id=music.length%2;
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, rId);
    id++;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to play a diffrent sound on every second click?

For this :

**1.** Store all raw file id's in an Integer Array.like:

```
int arrRawFiles ={R.raw.soho,R.raw.soho2,R.raw.soho3}
```

**2.** On `onClick` of Button generates a random integer according to Array length and then get raw file id from Array using that number:

```
  public void onClick(View v) 
   { 
     int index = new Random().nextInt(arrRawFiles.length);
     MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,index);
     mp.start(); 
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MediaPlayer mp;    
int clickCount=0;
one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 
public void onClick(View v) 
{ 
 if(clickCount %2 ==0){
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);
 }
 else{
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.another);
 }
 mp.start();
 clickCount++;
} });
```

Answer (score 0):

it's very simple. look at sample code and try...

```
        final boolean isFirstSound = true;
        Button one = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);
        final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.second_sound);
        one.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                isFirstSound = !isFirstSound;
                if(isFirstSound)
                    mp.start();
                else
                    mp2.start();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put the reference to the audio clip into an array

```
int[] audio={R.raw.clip1,R.raw.clip2};
for(i=0;i<audio.length;i++){

//your MediaPlayer Code here

}
```

i didnt try this , but you will get the idea of how to play many clips.
good luck

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ButtonPlayer implements View.OnClickListener {
    private final int[] sounds;
    private int soundIndex = -1;

    public ButtonPlayer(int... sounds) {
        this.sounds = sounds;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (sounds.length != 0) {
            soundIndex++;
            soundIndex = soundIndex % sounds.length;
            MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, sounds[soundIndex]);
            mp.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Then somewhere in your code:

```
Button one = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
one.setOnClickListener(new ButtonPlayer(
                           R.raw.first_composition,
                           R.raw.second_composition));
```

You can optimize this class later, by generating 'n' media players for each sound in constructor. But it's is task of optimization, not of implementation.

And of course always try to create independent classes for even small features. Don't clutter up activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int count=0;
    Button one = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);

    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            count++;

            if(count%2==1) {
                //play first sound
            }else{
                //play second sound
            }

        } });
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
boolean playFirst = true;
 final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);
        final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.second_sound_soho);
buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(playFirst == true){
             mp.start(); 
            playFirst = false;
        }else{
             mp2.start(); 
            playFirst = true;
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want switch between 2 sounds, I think you don't need a boolean or int value for check first time
Just check if sound1 is playing -> stop sound1 and open sound2 and opposite

```
final MediaPlayer mp1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.soho);
final MediaPlayer mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.second_sound);

buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mp1.isPlaying()){
             mp1.stop();
             mp2.start(); 
        }else{
             mp2.stop();
             mp1.start(); 
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this help

Comment: @H.Brooks why you think sound mp1 will never play, have you test it. correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I just tested it, when I press the button the first time it plays sound1, when I press it again nothing happens. I already marked one of the answers correct but I would like to use your approach.

Comment: the idea is, when you press button first time, the mp1 isPlaying, then you press the button again I will check mp1 is playing or not
if it playing, I will play mp2

Comment: may be I known the problem, may be your sound is too short, so when you press the button at second time, the mp1 is stop (not is playing)

Comment: Now I know my approach is not correct, thank you so much for correct me. I will think about another way later ;)